# Converting date in DD/MM/YY formate and order by it

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table having two column 1) ProductId(int) 2) PublishDate(varchar)
data is like following

```
ProductId   PublishDate
73          22/01/97
56          17/09/90
56          01/09/90
69          15/05/13
69          09/05/13
```

I have to get record from this table but in PublishDate Order by Desc,
as PublishDate is varchar, I am not able to do this can anyone please help me for this.

I have tried following query:

```
SELECT T.ProductId,
       T.MYDATE
FROM
(
SELECT     ProductId, CONVERT(varchar(max), PublishDate , 101) AS MYDATE
FROM         DateValidation

) T
ORDER BY T.MYDATE DESC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Here is the SQLFIddel Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e843b/13)**

**below is the Query Which You can try**

```
Select ProductId,
       Convert(Date,substring(PublishDate,4,3) + 
                    substring(PublishDate,1,3) + 
                    substring(PublishDate,7,2))               
  From DateValidation
 Order By 2 Desc
```

Answer (score 3):

Yo don't need to change date format because it is stored in your needed format ( it is stored as varchar, this is a **dirty** pattern).

But your issue is sorting by date. To sort by calendar date **you need to convert varchar to a valid date**:

```
SELECT     ProductId, PublishDate
  FROM     DateValidation
 ORDER BY  CONVERT(DATE, PublishDate, 103) desc
```

**I encourage to you to store dates in a date format but varchar.**

Comment: This is the better of the two answers as it fixes an underlying issue - storing dates as varchar. The only problem may be if the original schema can't be modified, in which case the other answer may be useful...but it still makes me cringe thinking about dates stored as strings!

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
SELECT ProductId,CONVERT(date,PublishDate,3)
FROM DateValidation 
order by 2 desc
```